# Real Time signalR in ASP.NET error in .ContainsKey

Tags: real-time, signalr, signalr-hub

I tried to chat with SignalR ised and ASP.Net (VB)
When running, works perfectly with the first user, but the login with another user get an error:

Error: Overflow

Please help, I'm new with realtime applications

```
Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task
        Dim myRoomId = "XXXX"
        Dim myUserId = IdentityUser.UserCode 
        SyncLock connections
            If Not connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId) Then
                connections(myRoomId) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))()
            End If
            If Not connections(myRoomId).ContainsKey(myUserId) Then ' <<<<<--- Error
                connections(myRoomId)(myUserId) = New List(Of String)()
            End If
            connections(myRoomId)(myUserId).Add(Me.Context.ConnectionId)
        End SyncLock
        Return MyBase.OnConnected()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you're locking the object "connections" and trying to change it inside SyncLock which is not allowed.

Use an empty object to lock in SyncLock, it should be public and shared.
Also , you should not use "OnConnect()" event becuase it will fire everytime on hub method call

like this

```
Private Shared _lock_connections As New Object

Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task
Dim myRoomId = "XXXX"
Dim myUserId = IdentityUser.UserCode
SyncLock _lock_connections
    If Not connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId) Then
        connections(myRoomId) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))()
    End If
    If Not connections(myRoomId).ContainsKey(myUserId) Then ' <<<<<--- Error
        connections(myRoomId)(myUserId) = New List(Of String)()
    End If
    connections(myRoomId)(myUserId).Add(Me.Context.ConnectionId)
End SyncLock
Return MyBase.OnConnected()
End Function
```